# "a high forehead" meaing

Tags: meaning-in-context

i came across this phrase while reading the novel The Death of The Heart by Elizabeth Bowen. I wonder what it means. 
Does it mean literally she has a high forehead on her face or idiomatically means arrorgant, condescending like 'a big head'?

"She insists on our being something or other - what, I'm not quite sure."
"A couple of cads - What a high forehead she's got."
"All the better to think about better, my dear."
"All the same, I wonder where she got that distinction. From what you say, her mother was quite a mess.
...... 
"High foreheads suggest violence to me." (p. 33)

Comment: It doesn't have to but generally a *high forehead* indicates intelligence or cerebral as opposed to emotional thinking; often both.

A cartoon brainiac scientist has a *high forehead* in the same way a Neanderthal or a moron has a *slope head*.